# "CudaLaunch returned (0x9)", and program timing issues

Tags: matrix, cuda, gpu, timing

I wrote a CUDA program, I have two questions about this program.

1. When I call the kernel function, I know that ***block_len*** must be <= 1024, but I still set ***block_len***> 1024. When I debugged with cuda-gdb and Nsight, there was an expected "cudaLaunch returned (0x9)" error. If I run the program without debug, the program runs smoothly and the result of the calculation is the same as using the CPU (without parallelism), indicating that my calculations are correct. Why the wrong program can get the correct result？
2. The program will calculate an ***length * length*** matrix A, the calculation of each element of A is done by one thread, ngridDim is set to (1,1). When ***length*** <32, the execution time of

   ```
   kernel <<< (1,1), (length, length) >>>
   ```

   changes according to the regularity of the size of ***length***. When ***length***> 32, the time spent by the kernel suddenly decreases 100-1000 times. I first suspect that my timing code is wrong, but after checking, I think there is no mistake. Later, I will attach the timing code.What causes such a result？

   ```
   dim3 dimBlock(length, length);
   dim3 dimGrid(1, 1);

   float a2;
   cudaEvent_t t1, t2;
   cudaEventCreate(&t1);
   cudaEventCreate(&t2);

   cudaEventRecord(t1, 0);
   kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dev_d, dev_D);
   cudaEventRecord(t2, 0);

   cudaEventSynchronize(t1);
   cudaEventSynchronize(t2);
   cudaEventElapsedTime(&a2,t1,t2);
   printf("kernel time: %f (ms)\n",a2);
   ```

If length=32,the kernel time is:

```
    kernel time: 37.341919 (ms)
```

If length=33,the kernel time is:

```
    kernel time: 0.004128 (ms)
```

**Some information of my device:**

[image: Information of my devices screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a complete code.  However:

1. It may be that the correct results are still in memory from the previous run.  When you set `length` > 32, then you have an illegal kernel launch, and your kernel will not run or produce any results.  You can confirm this by clearing the output data before the kernel launch.  For example, if `dev_D` contains the output of the kernel, then do something like this:

   ```
   cudaMemset(dev_D, 0, length*length*sizeof(dev_D[0]));
   kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dev_d, dev_D);
   ```

   if you do that, and the kernel fails to run, you should definitely get 0 in `dev_D` instead of the expected result.
2. When the `length` parameter is greater than 32, you are requesting more than 1024 threads per block, which is illegal in CUDA.  So the kernel does not run (use proper CUDA error checking if you want to confirm this.)  When the kernel does not run, the measured launch time is much shorter than when the kernel does run.

Comment: I confirmed the way you said, your answer is correct. Thank you very very much.